# Making h2 clickable

Tags: jquery

So basically, I have something like this:

`<h2 class="clickable">Hello</h2>`

And I want to make it clickable. I know it's kind of a strange question because I can just insert an `a` tag in there but this is how I need to do it right now. How would I do this? Is it anything like the code below? I'm kind of lost.

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).attr("href");
     return false;
});
```

Comment: In the current state your `h2` element has no `href`-attributem so this will not work. I **think** this is not valid HTML, so you should pick one of the new HTML5 custom `data-...` attributes.

Comment: What you have is correct and works. http://jsfiddle.net/DmSEP/2/. Just add a href attribute to h2.

Comment: _Info: W3c Online Validation_

line 7 column 50 - Error: Attribute href not allowed on element h2 at this point. -- Use a custom data-attribute like: `data-href="..."`

Comment: So why can't you add an anchor tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a target URL (what you are referring to with `href`). The correct way for that in HTML5 would be a data attribute.

This is the HTML5:

```
<h2 data-href="http://google.com/">My heading</h2>
```

This is the JS:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).data("href");
     return false;
});
```

If you want the new link to open in a new window, use this code:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
     window.open($(this).data("href"), 'new_window');
     return false;
});
```

Comment: How would I add a target `_blank` to it?

Comment: Use window.open instead of window.location (added it to the answer).

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that the `h2` does not *have* an attribute of `href`.

If you were to add a `href` attribute to it, it'd work; as shown in [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HLyJ6/).

Obviously the `href` attribute on the `h2` in non-standard; you might want to conform to the HTML5 standard at least, and stick the `url` in a `data-` attribute;

```
<h2 class="clickable" data-url="http://www.google.co.uk">Click Me</h2>
```

You could then use the `data()` method to retrieve it;

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).data("url");
     return false;
});
```

A Fiddle of this can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HLyJ6/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
     window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

Put your path instead of stackoverflow.com

Comment: This would link all the clickable headers to the same URI. This is not reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's kinda like the code you wrote, but the `$(this).attr("href")` references to the HREF of the H2, which has no HREF. Also, don't forget about the document ready, otherwise it might not work eather.

The code below, will find a HREF within the parent of the H2 tag, and go's to that URL.

```
$(function(){
    $(".clickable").click(function(){
         window.location=$(this).parent().find("a").attr("href");
         return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap the text of the `<h2>` elements with an anchor tag.

```
$('.clickable').wrapInner('<a href="..." />');
```

Comment: Quote: "I know it's kind of a strange question because I can just insert an `a` tag in there"

Comment: +1 I don't know why you got a -1, this is a perfectly valid option, might not be the best, but it is still valid!